# MapReduce job is not running on a HADOOP 2.6.0 (Multi node cluster)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have done Hadoop 2.6.0 Multi node cluster setup successfully on 4 machines(1 master and 3 slaves). But when I'm trying to run a simple word count job on cluster it gets stuck.

It's stuck here:

```
:~$ hadoop jar ~/MY_MAP_JARS/wordcount_f2.jar /input/crime /output/cc1
18/07/31 02:25:04 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/192.168.10.150:8032
18/07/31 02:25:06 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
18/07/31 02:25:10 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
18/07/31 02:25:11 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
18/07/31 02:25:11 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
18/07/31 02:25:12 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1533029038340_0001
18/07/31 02:25:13 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1533029038340_0001
18/07/31 02:25:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1533029038340_0001/
18/07/31 02:25:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1533029038340_0001
```

Sometimes it stuck on map phase:

```
18/07/31 02:27:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1533029038340_0003
18/07/31 02:28:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1533029038340_0003 running in uber mode : false
18/07/31 02:28:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
```

Sometimes map phase completed but reduce phase not running:

```
18/07/31 02:26:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1533029038340_0002
18/07/31 02:26:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1533029038340_0002 running in uber mode : false
18/07/31 02:26:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/07/31 02:26:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
```

**Cluster details:**

**On Master:**

RAM   : 6  GB |
HDD   : 20 GB |
Vcore : 4 |
Daemons: NameNode, Resource Manager, Secondary NN(default)

**On Slaves:** (All 3 slave nodes has same configuration)

RAM  : 4  GB |
HDD  : 20 GB |
Vcore: 4 |
Daemons: Data Node and Node manager

**My hadoop conf file:** (I exactly copied below mentioned configuration to all my nodes(master and slaves).

*core-site.xml:*

```
<configuration>
 <property>
 <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://master:50000</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

*hdfs-site.xml:*

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>2</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
  <value>file:/home/aroon/hadoop_store260/name-dir</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
 <value>file:/home/aroon/hadoop_store260/data-dir</value>
</property>
```

*mapred-site.xml:*

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

*yarn-site.xml:*

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>master</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
```

*slaves*

```
slave1
slave2
slave3
```

Could anyone please sort out this issue clearly, because similar questions were asked and answered and most of them are difficult to understand. If anyone could answer this question clearly, it could be helpful to newbies like me.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

PS: CONTAINER LOG(stderr)

Please find the container error log here: https://pastebin.com/VpzfU7Dr

Comment: You have to specify class file name(like WordCount) after `hadoop jar ~/MY_MAP_JARS/wordcount_f2.jar`.      you can refer this example:  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v1.0

Comment: While exporting jar from eclipse itself I selected the class file name. However, that's not mandatory if we already mentioned the driver class before.

Comment: Try adding IP address and hostname of all nodes in /etc/hosts file in all nodes.

Comment: Yes, I have done all those things. I found the issue is because of no memory for resource manger to  allocate jobs, I used Ubuntu 18, so it took so much memory. Now, I changed ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 14, it's working fine.